# Simulation stopping abruptly

Tags: r, simulation, batch-processing

I wanted to simulate rotations of fixed no of totebins (here the number is 6 indicating 6 totebins) between two production lines via one vehicle of capacity 6. One condition is to use transport only if 6 totebins are available or wait. My simulation is stopping after the batch command is executed. If i remove the batch command it works fine.

Is this structure right?
Should I use other type of generator?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
library(simmer)
library(parallel)
library(simmer.bricks)
library(simmer.plot)
library(magrittr)

  set.seed(333)
  num_tote_bins<-6   #deciding no of totebins to rotate

  totebin_movement <- trajectory("totebin_movement") %>%
    timeout(1,tag = "Inspection") %>% # Adding inspection time
    
    # Maintenance
    seize("Maintenance_Dept", 1) %>%
    timeout(1) %>% # Maintenance time of one day
    release("Maintenance_Dept", 1) %>%

    
    # Production
    seize("Production_Line_1", 1) %>%
    timeout(1) %>% # Production time of one day
    release("Production_Line_1", 1) %>%
    
    # Finished Goods Inventory
    seize("FG Inv", 1) %>%
    timeout(1) %>% # Delay time
    release("FG Inv", 1) %>%
    
    # Transportation
    seize("transportation", 6) %>%
    batch(n = 6)%>%
    separate()%>%
    timeout(4) %>% # Transportation time
    release("transportation", 6) %>%
    
    # Production_Line_2
    seize("Production_Line_2", 1) %>%
    timeout(2) %>% 
    release("Production_Line_2", 1) %>%
    
    # Return Transportation
    seize("return_transport", 1) %>%
    timeout(4) %>% # Return transport time
    release("return_transport", 1)%>%
    rollback(times = Inf, target = "Inspection")
  
    
    get_palette <- scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual", palette = 1)
    plot(totebin_movement, fill = get_palette, verbose = TRUE)
    
    
    totebin_simulation<- simmer("totebin_simulation")%>%
                      add_resource("Maintenance_Dept",capacity = 2 )%>%
                      add_resource("Production_Line_1",capacity = 6)%>%
                      add_resource("FG Inv",capacity = 20)%>%
                      add_resource("transportation",capacity =6 )%>%
                      add_resource("Production_Line_2",capacity = 6)%>%
                      add_resource("return_transport",capacity = 6)


    for (i in 1:num_tote_bins) {
         totebin_simulation <- totebin_simulation %>%
         add_generator(paste0("ToteBin_", i), trajectory = totebin_movement, distribution = at(0))
                            }


    totebin_simulation <-run(totebin_simulation, until = 365)  # Adjust the duration as needed
   
    rotation<-get_mon_arrivals(totebin_simulation, per_resource = TRUE )
    
    resource_usage<-get_mon_resources(totebin_simulation)
```

Comment: your `add_generator()` call includes the distribution `at(0)` - what's the `at()` function from?  Returning a negative or missing value here stops the simulation.

Comment: This function is supposed to make available all totebins at time 0 for processing.

Comment: ah, is see, `at()` is a convenience function provided by simmer, sorry.

Comment: from what I can see in the support documents, `batch()` and `release()` are supposed to be used outside of the `seize() / release()` pairs - you batch before seizing not afterwards.

Comment: Will you please share resource for this documentation. anyways I used the batch/separate function before seize()/release() of transportation . Still no difference.   
    # Transportation
    batch(n = 6)%>%
    seize("transportation", 6) %>%
    timeout(4) %>% # Transportation time
    release("transportation", 6) %>%
    separate()%>%

Comment: reference:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/simmer/simmer.pdf   various guides: https://r-simmer.org/articles/

Comment: the order would be `batch() |> separate() |> seize() |> release() as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't access the package from here for testing

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, but the result is same with the given sequence. If you get to run this code on your workstation, let me know your results too.

Comment: @Compo: Still the same result. Stimulation does not proceed beyond FGINV step

Comment: @RohitSSS, why have you tagged me in a comment? I did not make one to you, nor have I taken part in the conversation. All I have done is to remove your invalid tag, and improve how your code is displayed on our site.

Comment: I apologize for tagging. I am new here and still trying to learn. I did not realize that you have not answered but just changed the appearance of the question.